# iPhone 4, Push Notifications At Night Time, Any Way to Stop?

Tags: iphone, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm wanting to know if there's a way to stop push notifications, or at least stop their sound during nighttime?

I don't want to silence the phone, because I need the alarm to sound in the morning. It'd be nice if I could specify that push notifications should only come through between certain hours, or be quiet during the night...

Thanks.

Comment: This should probably ve on Super User…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is now redundant as iOS now has Do Not Disturb mode that can be scheduled.

Answer (score 4):

I believe alarms will still sound when the switch is set to vibrate. Otherwise, what good would they be?

Comment: I can confirm this. I set my iPhone 4 on vibrate each night and the alarms still go off loud and clear.

Comment: Thanks. It'd be nice if the notifications option panel had more options, like times of day they can sound, but for now at least, I'll just flip the switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alarms do sound when the vibrate switch is on. I switch mine off all the time for that same reason and still get up in the morning

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreak your phone, and install one of these apps:

Auto Silent: http://iphonepackers.info/

SBSchedule: http://tom.zickel.org/iphone/cydia/sbschedule/depiction/

Comment: I like the look of those apps, but I'm not prepared to go down the Jailbreaking route... Thanks though. :)